# How to do child-to-Parent query for Standard objects?

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
for(Contact con : [SELECT  Name,(SELECT Phone FROM Contact) WHERE ID IN =: AccountId)
```

Comment: The online documentation covers this well. See [Understanding Relationship Names](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(Contact con : [SELECT Account.Name, Phone FROM Contact WHERE AccountID  = :AccountId])
```